# Where do you put an encryption key on a public facing server?

Tags: c#, security, encryption, nservicebus

I am using NServiceBus with MSMQ between my web application and service and I need to be able to encrypt the message payload so that if a message gets queued locally on the web server (service host is down) that sensitive data can't be viewed.

Because the web server is public facing, I am not only required to encrypt data that may be serialized to disk in anyway, but I also cannot store the encryption key on the web server.

I've considered using DPAPI to store the key, but since the key would be stored on the host I don't know yet if that runs afoul of the requirement or not. The other option I have considered is that when the web application starts it could request the key from a service and hold it in memory for the life of the application pool.

I haven't had to work with this level of requirement on encryption before and would like to find out what others are doing and get some feedback on the ideas mentioned above.

Comment: Whatever you do, hire a security consultant to verify the efficacy of your design/implementation. If you're not an expert in this field, it's trivially easy to make a mistake and the costs of that mistake could be enormous compared to the costs of paying someone to help you get it right. cf. Heartland Payment Systems.

Comment: This does not strike me as a problem that asymmetric cryptography solves.

Comment: The asymmetric key would at least reduce the probability of an observer reading existing state from disk.  Though with the asymmetric key in hand an observer could use that to start a brute force attack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the source from which NServiceBus pulls its encryption key - this is described in the docs here: http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/security/encryption

This way, you can avoid having this sensitive information reside out on the DMZ.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know that was an option. After discussion with our security director we'll be requesting the key from a non-public server and store it in-memory.

Answer (score 7):

Can you use public/private key encryption?  Then you only need to public key on the server, and the data is decrypted using the private key elsewhere.

Comment: It's worth noting that public-private encryption may require a lot of cryptographically secure entropy (for the message keys, IVs, and padding) - this may be a problem at high throughputs.

Comment: Yes I agree - asymmetric keys would help greatly. To achieve a robust enough encryption could take serious horsepower in a high-throughput system. We turned to crypto-hardware in one of our scenarios - expensive, tricky to integrate, worth it tho'.

Comment: sounds great, but I'm not sure I can get the cost approved. Like you said w/o dedicated hardware, asymmetric encryption would choke throughput. I considered using asymmetric for the key only, but the key to decrypt the key would still need to be stored where the web application could access it.

Answer (score 1):

"Because the web server is public facing, I am not only required to encrypt data that may be serialized to disk in anyway, but I also cannot store the encryption key on the web server."

Seems like this is the only constraint to focus on - validate that it is true for starters.  It'll rule out DPAPI + local key-store approaches.

It's plausible to deliver the key by service, but that service still has to authenticate the caller.  If your server is compromised masquerading as a legitimate caller, observing the call etc. are all possible.  In addition if you stored the key only in-memory, that memory is still discoverable in a debugger or memory dump, elevated privilage process etc.

Hardware encryption cards are the only way to overcome the latter scenarios.

Comment: I think you're right about delivering the key by service. While I've been told we can't store the key on the web server, I doubt I'll get approval for a hardware encryption card. I've been looking more at DPAPI and I may be able to get approval for it if I'm using the user scope instead of machine scope. My manager is in meetings all day so I'll have to wait to get approval until then.

Answer (score 0):

The best place to [encrypt is at the queue level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms700225%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). You do this by [sending private messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms699845.aspx) and creating queues that only accept private messages. While you can set the queue privacy level when you create the queue at creation time, I'm not sure if you can configure NServiceBus to send private messages.

Comment: Yes, I've looked at this, but according to the docs in your links: " When private messages are sent, Message Queuing ensures that the body of the messages are kept encrypted from the moment they leave the source queue manager to the moment they reach their destination queue manager." I need the message encrypted while it is in the queue as well and MSMQ doesn't seem to support this natively.